# Compile error in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, darwin

I'm trying to build APIs and the compiler does not recognize the libraries, these are installed within the include folder, thus I try to compile and seguite error appears:

```
$ gcc-llo SimpleSend.cpp SimpleSend.cpp: 5:10:
fatal error: 'osc/OscOutboundPacketStream.h' file not found
# include "osc / OscOutboundPacketStream.h"
  ^
1 error generated.
```

What can be this error?

Comment: You didn't tell gcc-llo where it should look to find 'osc/OscOutboundPacketStream.h'

Comment: I'm assuming gcc-llo is a c++ compiler with the same syntax as `g++`? If so `gcc-llo -o SimpleSend -I path/to/includes SimpleSend.cpp`. If not, why aren't you using `g++`?

Comment: Yes I said, check the first line.

Comment: Still the error persists.

Comment: "The first line" tells me nothing. If your mention of "within the include folder" means "within the include subfolder of the current directory I am in" then use `gcc-llo -o SimpleSend -I ./include SimpleSend.cpp`. Also, this still doesn't tell me if `gcc-llo` is a c++ compiler, from the name it seems like it's not, but just a normal c compiler. If this is the case you'll have to manually link using `-lstdc++`. Instead of doing that, use `g++`.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
# include "osc / OscOutboundPacketStream.h"
```

is wrong, too many spaces, especially in the path. Rewrite like this:

```
#include "osc/OscOutboundPacketStream.h"
```

By default, the `gcc` precompiler [looks](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) in `/usr/local/include` for include files. To tell the precompiler to look there instead of the current working directory, use angle brackets instead of quotes:

```
#include <osc/OscOutboundPacketStream.h>
```

Comment: Sorry if poorly formulated question, but this is the error that the compiler emits per account can not find the library in the system.

Comment: Show the code. And make sure the `.h` file you refer to exists and is readable.

Comment: This file is in the /usr/local/include folder, it should not be in the /usr/local/bin?

Comment: @user3509063 no, use angle brackets in that case. Using quotes makes the precompiler to look in the current working dir. See my updated answer.

Comment: MacBook-Pro-de-Lucas:oscpack_1_1_0 marciobazanaokabe$ gcc -llo SimpleSend.cpp 
ld: library not found for -llo
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

seems like you've made many typos in this string:

```
# include "osc / OscOutboundPacketStream.h"
```

maybe it should be something like this?

```
#include "osc/OscOutboundPacketStream.h"
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of @BartFriederichs answer.

Comment: This is the error that appears, he can not find this library in the system.

Comment: ok, then just for curiosity, can you show us content of file named `SimpleSend.cpp`?

Comment: `#include "osc/OscOutboundPacketStream.h"`
`#include "ip/UdpSocket.h"`

`#define ADDRESS "127.0.0.1"`
`#define PORT 7000`
`#define OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE 1024`
`int main(int argc, char* argv[]){`
`(void) argc; // suppress unused parameter warnings`
`(void) argv; // suppress unused parameter warnings`
`UdpTransmitSocket transmitSocket( IpEndpointName( ADDRESS, PORT ) );`
`char buffer[OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE]`
`osc::OutboundPacketStream p( buffer, OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE );`
    
    ...continue